# Binding to @Input on extended component is not working

Tags: angular

I have the following scenario:

```
 export class ComponentA 
{
  @Input model
}

@Component({
 template:
 `
  <h5>{{model.name}}</h3>
 `
 })

 export class ComponentB extends ComponentA
 {
   @Output changed = new EventEmitter();
 }

 @Component({
  template:
   `
   <component-b [model]="myModel"> </component-b> 
   `
   })

  export class ComponentC{

   public myModel:any = {name:'bla'}
  }
```

The binding to the model is not working.
BUT , if I will remove the @Output member it will work!

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be by design that `@Input()`s are not inherited. See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5794

Comment: It would be very nice if they were though.. :)

Comment: Thanks!
I guess that when I remove the output and then the Input inheritance works is a BUG?
Can you understand why we can't inherit @Inputs?

Comment: I just remembered seeing the issue and looked it up when I saw your question. The issue is not closed therefore it might still be considered to implement it. I was involved in similar discussions about Dart about inheriting `implements OnInit` (`implements SomeLifcycleInterface` is mandatory in Dart). They won't support it currently because it causes performance issues when building on large applications with the current build infrastructure. They definitely want to support inheriting lifecycle interface implementations. It might be the same reason@Input()` doesn't work currently.

Comment: I think it has to do with order of execution, decorators are run before constructor. It might even be at compile time? Think I read that somewhere, but cant find it and I don't know that much about TypeScript (:

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but maybe it still helps someone. It does work (tested in Angular 14) when you decorate the base class with `@Directive()`.
My base class is also marked abstract, not sure if that's necessary. So it'll look something like this:

```js
@Directive()
export abstract class BaseClass {
  @Input()
  whatever: boolean;
}
```

... and extend that class in your component class.